# Update second select options on the basis of first select options MVC 4 razor

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, drop-down-menu

I have 2 select options and i am populating values from database 
Now how do i update second select options on the basis of first select options in MVC 4 razor syntax i have no idea i tried
i am new to mvc development i just need a clue

```
            $("#selectTown").change(function () {

            if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {

                $(this).data('options', $('#selectstreet option').clone());
            }
            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
            $('#selectstreet').html(options);
        });
```

i tried jquery above and its working if values are static but wont work now as i am getting values from database. Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Its called cascading dropdownlists. And if you search it you will find plenty of examples. Refer also this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general solution of cascade drop down list of country and cities it can be implement for any other scenario in the same way

i have a class City

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CascadeDropdownLists.Models
{
public class City
{

    public City()
    { }

    public City(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Then i have HomeController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CascadeDropdownLists.Models;

namespace CascadeDropdownLists.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetCities(int id)
    {
       // List<Models.City> cities = new List<Models.City>();

        List<City> cities = new List<City>();

        if (id == 1)
        {
            cities.Add(new City(1, "Lahore"));
            cities.Add(new City(2, "Islamabad"));
        }
        else {
            cities.Add(new City(1, "Paris"));
            cities.Add(new City(2, "Alaska"));

        }
        return this.Json(cities,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
}
```

And finally in the index.cshtml file

```
@{
Layout = null;
 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#countrySelector").change(function () {
             var countryId = $("#countrySelector").val(); 
             $("#citySelctor option").remove();
             $.getJSON("/home/GetCities?id=" + countryId, function (data) {
                 $("#citySelctor").append('<option>-Select City-</option>');
                 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                     $("#citySelctor").append('<option value=' + item.Id + '>' + item.Name + '</option>');
                     //alert('Id = ' + item.Id + " Name = " + item.Name);
                 });

             });

         });

     });
```

```html
<body>
       <div>
       <div>
       <select id="countrySelector">
       <option value="0">-Select Country-</option>
       <option value="1">Pakistan</option>
       <option value="2">France</option>
  
        </select>
        <div>
        <select id="citySelctor">
        <option>-Select City-</option>
      
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
</body>
```